# Windows 7 gets hung when it tries to load the file "classpnp.sys"

Tags: windows-7, boot, freeze

I installed a new SSD into my desktop, installed Windows 7 Pro on it, and applied all the available updates to it (restarting several times in the process). Now my computer takes forever to boot. It used to start at the very end of the "Starting Windows" animation, but now it doesn't load until about 10 minutes later. When it finishes loading, it's as fast as it was before it started doing this.

I know that this issue is not caused by failing hardware as I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it after having this problem and it booted in (Literally) 5 seconds.

Following others suggestions on various websites I have tried reinstalling windows (I think I'm on my 3rd installation), running system restore, running the windows recovery tool, running checkdisk, running tests on my RAM, booting in safe mode, removing any unnecessary hard drives and USB drives, and running fc /SCANNOW /OFFBOOTDIR=C:\ /OFFWINDIR=C:\Windows  in the command prompt in windows recovery.

Comment: I think you got mistaken as to what this site is about.

Comment: If you have tested all those it might be an issue with BIOS settings or corruption. Try changing values of settings related to plug-and-play, disk drives, pcie and USB to safe defaults. If that doesn't work update BIOS. (No guarantees, obviously, but that's what I would try next, and you seem desperate enough...)

Comment: If this problem exists after multiple installations of an operating system that indicates a hardware problem not a software problem.